# How to keep chronometer up and running in swipe activity (view pager)?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, chronometer

I am trying to start timer in `getView` method based on if `convertView` is null or not, but it does not work - the timer always start to tick from zero.

**Edit:**
I can now persist with current time by using setBase, but something seems to be wrong here

```
chrono.setBase(1499331775800);
chrono.start();  // Displays 00:-1499331775800
```

**Edit2:**
setBase takes epoch time that starts in year 1970, so if chronometer shows "`54:52`" then the setBase needs to take a long value `4755292`, since it's equal to `GMT: Wednesday, 25 February 1970 00:54:52`

Comment: Try save and reset its base time via `setBase()`.

Comment: Yes I am actually trying to do this, and the method itself works, but I am doing something wrong when setting the base value. Does it actually get a epoch time as argument, and then calculate difference between now?